# Drop down menu auto changing link

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have a problem with my menu. Problem is on web http://www.zicherka.cz/ and is with main menu. If is link in menu single, it can be navigated to URL changed by me. BUT. If is link as drop-down, link of main (first) item is automatically changed to only /#. Where is problem? Template is copied by http://html.zicherka.cz/ 
Thanks for opinions

Comment: Post the problem code here.

Comment: use **stack snippet** to write your code here for detailed analysis

Comment: It's the right behavior. The first item triggers the drop down to show. If you assign it a href you will never see the drop down

Comment: @LelioFaieta well if your dropdown is getting activated by just hovering then hrefing it won't be a problem.. but yes if it's activated by clicking then it would be a problem for sure

Comment: Hi, this is PHP code, where is the maybe problem: http://pastebin.com/pUxNKP1Z